# Android Firebase Data Not Loading Until Refresh

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an app in Android Studio and am using Firebase to store/retrieve data. This works fine, but when I save the retrieved data to a local variable and then attempt to display the data in a listview it doesn't work until I refresh the view.

This is my OnCreate function:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_chores);

    //get database reference and user data
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://...");
    user = (User) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("user");

    configureBackButton();
    updateFromFirebase();
    display();
}
```

This is the update function (variable map is a global var):

```
private void updateFromFirebase() {
    final ArrayList<String> list;
    final String name = user.getName().toLowerCase();

    mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot child : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                ArrayList<String> list;
                String name;
                name = child.getKey();
                list = (ArrayList)child.getValue();
                map.put(name.toLowerCase(), list);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            ...
        }
    });
    list = map.get(name);
    if(list==null) return;

    final ListView list_xml = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    list_xml.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And this is the display function:

```
private void display() {
    final ArrayList<String> list;
    final String name = user.getName().toLowerCase();

    list = map.get(name);
    if(list==null) return;

    final ListView list_xml = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    list_xml.setAdapter(adapter);

    list_xml.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String item = adapter.getItem(position);
            list.remove(item);
            map.put(name, list);

            CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);

            Snackbar sb = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Item Removed!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
            sb.show();

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    }
```

Any insights to why it doesn't display the first time would be appreciated.

Comment: After the onDataChange, you will have every element you need from the firebase right? so try to set the adapter to your view there and it should work.

Comment: I tried to add my adapter code right after the onDataChange() but still within the addListenerForSingleValueEvent() and I kept getting errors saying it couldn't resolve constructor for the adapter, or it couldn't resolve a variable, and when I put the same block of code outside of addListenerForSingleValueEvent() but still within updateFromFirebase() (see updated post) no errors, but I get the same result as before - data appears only after I have already opened the view for a second time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since valueEventListener is an asynchronous function, it may not get the result right away, so I think it will be better if you update the UI, when the data is changed (onDataChange)

```
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot child : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            ArrayList<String> list;
            String name;
            name = child.getKey();
            list = (ArrayList)child.getValue();
            map.put(name.toLowerCase(), list);
        }
        //this is displaying result whenever change occurs
        display();
    }
```

Comment: Yes that has solved it, I did not know of the asynchronicity of that function, thank you!